# Validating dynamically generated fields nested within a dynamically generated field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, cocoon-gem

I have three models `Comapny`, `Person` and `Role` a Company `has_many :people`, a Person `has_many :roles` and a Company, `has_many :roles, through: :people`.  Here's where it gets fun: The number of people to a company and roles to a person are assigned using cocoon, meaning that I have a set of dynamically generated field within a set of dynamically generated fields.

The Problem I'm having is in validating the roles for the company.  For example, each company needs a President (`role.role_name="President"`)  So I set up the following: validation:

```
validate :final_incorporation

def company_validation
    errors.add(:company, "needs a president") if self.roles.where(role_name: "President").count==0
end
```

...and it works! ...sometimes.  If I comment out the validation and save the company with the person and the roles to the database, then put the validation back in and save it.  It passes validation.

However if I add a person and then a role of "President" for that person and try to submit with validation, it doesn't pass.

My guess, though I have no idea of how to get around it, is cocoons way of assigning a temporary id to each generated field is screwing up the association specified in the validation.

**So from the log:**

This passes validation:

```
 ..."people_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"fname"=>"test", "lname"=>"", "roles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"role_name"=>"President", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"5"}, "1"=>{"role_name"=>"Treasurer", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"6"}}}...
```

But this doesn't:

```
..."people_attributes"=>{"1455189047186"=>{"fname"=>"test", "lname"=>"", "roles_attributes"=>{"1455189059602"=>{"role_name"=>"President", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1455189066001"=>{"role_name"=>"Treasurer", "_destroy"=>"false"}}...
```

**Edit** This also doesn't pass validation (person previously saved but roles added)

```
..."people_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"fname"=>"test", "lname"=>"", "roles_attributes"=>{"1455195637658"=>{"role_name"=>"President", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1455195641046"=>{"role_name"=>"Treasurer", "_destroy"=>"false"}}...
```

Any ideas on how to get around this would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the issue is that since you're *creating* a new `Role`, it's not recognizing that any of your `people` have the role of `President`?

Comment: @RichardPeck I just reread your question and I'm not sure that's it.  The issue is that when I (using cocoon) add a `Person` and then add a `Role` to that person (also with cocoon) and then make that newly added role "President,"  it doesn't pass validation.  (Unless I first save it by disabling validation and then try submitting it for validation.  Then it's ok.)

Comment: So you're making a new role, or using one already in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def company_validation
    errors.add(:company, "needs a president") unless people.any?{|person| person.roles.any?{|role| role.role_name == "President" && !role.marked_for_destruction?}}
end
```

Comment: The one that avoids sql use worked perfectly (the method involving the scope, etc ran into the same problem).  My aim wasn't to perform a db query anyway.  I was simply interested in scanning the submitted data for a "President" role.  I shouldn't worry about the number of people; most of the time there are no more than 10 when this form is used.  Thanks!

Comment: So this works well? (I was just out and missed the action)

Comment: @RichardPeck the second method seems to.  It's a little more manual (with the little loop at the end) than I was expecting but no matter.

Comment: @RichardPeck Well this is embarrassing but I'm afraid it might be in your best interest to unlearn it.  I looked at the code again because I noticed I wasn't getting any errors and I realized that I put an `if` in place of `unless`.  With the mistake corrected, the above works exactly the same as my original validation: If it's already saved to the database it's fine, it it's not then `roles.any?` returns `false`.

Comment: hmm, so you still have the issue?

Comment: @RichardPeck yea unfortunately so. :-P

Comment: Let me look into it!

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I edited my answer and it should work now but it's quite ugly and inefficient. Hopefully neanderslob will think of something better :)

Comment: Thank you madam!  My apologies for accepting the answer initially, only later to discover that I'd botched my transcription of it.  This makes a lot more sense and, in spite of your own objection to its efficiency, is a HELL of a lot better than what I was about to cobble together in the controller.  Also, (for the sake of anyone else who comes across this answer) I added `&& role._destroy == false` so it will be compatible with the cocoon gem.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries :) I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Wow the new method is deep.